# can't assign variable name to filename in pdftk

Tags: php, pdf, pdftk

I am trying to run the following command in a  php script and for some reason it doesn't work, and i don't get any errors either:

```
shell_exec("pdftk Invoice.pdf fill_form invoice.fdf output" . $_POST["Job"] . ".pdf flatten");
```

But if i run the same command but actually give it a filename it works fine

```
shell_exec("pdftk Invoice.pdf fill_form invoice.fdf output testing.pdf flatten");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a space after output (within your string). If you echo your actual string you're generating there it's not going to read output testing.pdf, but outputtesting.pdf